# Byte[256] over TCP limiting to 5 characters

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

I am having an issue with a TCP server\client I am writing in .NET 3.5 (C#).

Whenever I transfer data using the code below, only 5 characters transfer to the server. How can I fix my code so that I have more than 5 characters transferring?

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(connectto.ToString(), portto);
Stream s = client.GetStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);

Byte[] data = new Byte[256];
data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("auth:" + adminPASS.Text);

s.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

data = new Byte[256];

String responseData = String.Empty;

Int32 bytes = s.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
```

The server is only getting the first 5 characters of whatever is transferred. The rest is lost.

Comment: can you verify adminPASS.Text is not empty? Also call s.Flush() when writing is done.

Comment: Even if I add a safeguard to ensure that the value of the text box is not empty, it seems that the data still does not go through. I also have a string with the text "connected", that is sent on initial connection to the server. In the output log in Visual Studio, I get this "got message conne" and then "got message" directly beneath it. I also tried using s.Flush(), and nothing changed.

Comment: You know you are not sending `Byte[256]` of data, you create a 256 big array but then immedatly throw it away when you do `data = System.Text.Encoding...` it is like you did `Byte[] data = ystem.Text.Encoding...` instead.

Comment: After doing some testing, I've been able to discover that only the data sent from the client to the server is lost. Data from the server to the client stays intact.

Answer (score 3):

[Stream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can return fewer bytes than requested, so you need to call it in a loop until EOF is reached, like this:

```
int bytes;
int offset = 0;

while ((bytes = s.Read(data, offset, data.Length - offset) != 0)
{
   offset += bytes;
}
```

Also, you never `Dispose()` your streams, so it's likely that they aren't getting flushed.  Use a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) around all your `IDisposable` objects.

Comment: I tried the code you said for the Stream.Read functions... so far it has only caused the client to hang and stop responding. Do I need to add this code to the stream writer as well?

Comment: @themsftcpu as he said, it will loop till the end EOF has been reached, so the sender needs to close the connection to stop the loop. If you are trying to fill `data.Length` bytes exactly you can add a `offset < data.Length && (bytes = ...` at the start.

Answer (score 1):

```
Byte[] data = new Byte[256];
```

this allocated 256 bytes

```
data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("auth:" + adminPASS.Text);
```

this throws away the 256 bytes and converts "auth:" + adminPASS.text to bytes

```
s.Write(data 0, data.length)
```

sends 5 bytes + the length of adminPASS.text

it looks like you are only sending around 5 bytes, especially if the adminPASS.text is empty

Comment: This is good information, but the missing data may well be caused by the fact that the buffer is not flushed (see John's answer and @payo's comment).

Comment: From the title it suggests he expects 256 bytes to be transferred. Which it most certainly is not.  You are right that a flush 'might' help, but is unlikely as it is rare for a send to break apart such a small message, so if he is getting 5 bytes, then it is unlikely that a flush will affect it

Answer (score 0):

Most of your objects implement IDisposable, so need to be in `using` blocks.

A `using` block ensures that the `Dispose` method is called. In this case, `Dispose` is what would have flushed buffers and waited until all data was sent.

Comment: That sounds more like a comment than an answer.  Elaborating on the reason the missing calls to IDisposable.Dispose() is causing the observed behavior would significantly improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the original code for getting the string to use on the server was,

```
mstrMessage = mstrMessage.Substring(0, 5);
```

so it was only reading the first 5 bytes of data. Changed this to bytesReceived.Length and it works fine.